# Emil Artin on visualization of matrices

Tags: matrices, reference-request, math-history, visualization

Someone called my attention to the fact that Emil Artin made very important remarks on the visual representation of matrices in some of his books. Could anyone tell me which precise book that is? Exact reference to the original would be welcome. If some excerpts on the topic could be shown, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Might it have been this one? ${}\qquad{}$

[http://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Algebra-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486801551](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486801551)

Comment: Are you sure?Having a look at his bibliography https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Artin I figured out it might be Artin, Emil (1959), Theory of algebraic numbers, Göttingen: Mathematisches Institut, MR 0132037 Reprinted in (Artin 2007).....any evidence from the book?

Comment: Not really, but it's the only thing listed on amazon that looked as if it might fit. ${}\qquad{}$